# Trying to make a Goal that is satisfied if another goal runs 10 times in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
r1(X,Z) :- backwards(X,Z).

r1_10(X,Z) :- 
    r1(X,Z),
```

I have this code. The idea is that r1_10 would be satisfied if r1 is satisfied 10 times. I am new to Prolog and I'm not sure how to really loop this properly. I was thinking about just brute forcing the same line 10 times, but I need to be able to do things like r1_30, so that would be a lot of code for no reason.

Thanks!

EDIT:
That answer helped a lot, but just to clarify what I was asking. Essentially, I have the goal r1 which calls my backwards/2 predicate which simply gets me the reverse of the list. I have two types of backwards/2 predicates, one including an accumulator and one not. The r1_10 is simply a goal that will eventually show me that the one using an accumulator is faster and better. The goal r1_10 is simply a way of running the goal r1 10 times. I'm pretty sure I don't need different results, I just need to be able to know that it will succeeded when r1 has finished 10 times. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "satisfied 10 times". Do you mean that the `r1/2` predicate would have 10 solutions? An example would be the goal `member(X, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])`, which, on backtracking would successively instantiate the variable `X` to each one of the list elements. If so, one solution could be to use the standard `findall/3` predicate to compute a list of all solutions to the goal and then to compute the length of the list. For example:

```
r1_10(X,Z) :-
    findall(_, r1(X,Z), Solutions),
    length(Solutions, 10).
```

This predicate could be easily generalized by using an additional argument to pass the number of solutions to check for. It could also be generalized by using yet another argument to pass the goal itself.

On the other hand, if you want to simply call a goal N times, you can define a predicate that takes a goal and a counter. For example:

```
call_n_times(N, Goal) :-
    between(1, N, _),  % generate, on backtracking, all numbers in the interval [1,N]
    once(Goal),
    fail.
call_n_times(_, _).
```

This definition, however, assumes that the goal never fails (or throws an error). It's not clear from your question what should happen if the goal cannot be satisfied N times. Should the caller fail in that case? If so, you will need a different definition. For example (assuming again that the goal never fails or throws an error):

```
call_n_times(0, _) :- !.  % green cut just to avoid a spurious choice-point
call_n_times(N, Goal) :-
    N > 0,
    once(Goal),
    M is N - 1,
    call_n_times(M, Goal).
```

But this definition can still be problematic. For example, if you pass a goal that is not ground, i.e. with variables in it, and calling the goal instantiates some of all of its variables in a way that prevents it from succeeding in the next step. One way to avoid this potential issue is to use the following compact definition:

```
call_n_times(N, Goal) :-
    forall(between(1,N,_), Goal).
```

`forall/2` and `between/3` are de facto standard predicates. The `forall/2` predicate is true when, for each solution of the first argument, the second argument is true (thus implementing a generate-and-test loop).

We could use some more details on what you want to accomplish, including the nature of the goals that you want to repeat.